# There is way to use ".then callback" with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There is way to use ".then callback" to console.log the "frog" coz i wanna see my token inside the async-storage.

---after i got my token so i need to attach it in header of a fetch call, someone know the way to do it ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const frog =  AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-TOKEN');
    console.log('THIS MY TOKEN', frog);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe you can simply do

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getItem = async () => {
        const frog = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-TOKEN');
        console.log('THIS MY TOKEN', frog);
    };
    getItem();
  }, []);
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-TOKEN')
        .then(token => {
            console.log('THIS MY TOKEN', token);
        });
  }, []);
```

In the first case, I'm creating an async function, enabling in this way the `await` keyword, in the second case I'm simply using `then`

Comment: the first is correct, but the second one not. The "frog" is given as argument of the `then` method, not as result of the entire function.

Comment: OKay, that's fine

Comment: after i got my token so i need to attach it in header of a fetch call, someone know the way to do it ?

Comment: @shira you can add your own header to the request passing `headers` as argument to the `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch